# Removing outline on image map area in html emails

Tags: html-email, imagemap

Is there any way to remove the outline on  image map area in a html email. Once i click the image in the email,the border appears on the map area. Outline:none,hidefocus,blur() doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Solved,
 I was trying the outline:none on the map tag instead of the area tag.
<area  style="outline:none" > does the trick.

Comment: In html emails,is there a way to make image non downloadable?